# How to create cowplot panel with side and top headings and a common legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, tmap, cowplot

I want to create a choropleth panel with side and top headings and a common legend.
I am plotting a choropleth over the state of Texas for four different scenarios. I want to show it as a 2x2 panel. I am using the `plot_grid` method from the R `cowplot` library to generate the panel.

Here's what I want it to look like,
[image]

Here's a snippet of the code that I have till now,

```r
CPC_grids_deviations <- merge(CPC_grids, tx_deviation_df)

create_grids_deviation_map <- function(data) {
  grids_deviation_map <- tm_shape(texas) +
    tm_borders() +
    tm_shape(CPC_grids_deviations) +
    # Setting fixed style so that all maps have a consistent, comparable scale
    tm_fill(col = data, palette = "Blues",  style = "fixed", breaks = c(0, 1, 21, 41, 61, 81, 101, 121, 140),
            legend.show = FALSE) +
    tm_borders(col = "grey60", lwd = 0.5) +
    tm_layout(frame = FALSE)

  return(tmap_grob(grids_deviation_map))
}


plot_grid(
  create_grids_deviation_map("total_cpc_90"), create_grids_deviation_map("total_chirps_90"),
  create_grids_deviation_map("total_cpc_70"), create_grids_deviation_map("total_chirps_70"),
  ncol = 2
)
```

And here's the output so far,
[image]

I am able to generate just the legend using the following code,

```
create_legend <- function(data) {
  legend <- tm_shape(texas) +
    tm_borders() +
    tm_shape(CPC_grids_deviations) +
    tm_fill(col = data, palette = "Blues", title = "Count", style = "fixed", breaks = c(0, 1, 21, 41, 61, 81, 101, 121, 140)) +
    tm_layout(legend.only = TRUE)

  return(legend)
}
create_legend("total_cpc_90")
```

But I am not sure how to include the generated legend in the panel as shown in the expected output.

Comment: Not familiar with tmap/sf, but why not use facets: https://pinjiahe.github.io/posts/2021/05/geom-sf-facet

Comment: any possibility you could share the data?

Answer (score 0):

Try `patchwork::plot_layout(guides = 'collect')`. See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html

```r
p1 <- create_grids_deviation_map("total_cpc_90")
p2 <- create_grids_deviation_map("total_chirps_90")
p3 <- create_grids_deviation_map("total_cpc_70")
p4 <- create_grids_deviation_map("total_chirps_70")


p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 +
  plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

To add the side and top headings, use `patchwork::plot_annotation()`. See https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html